# What's the best practice backup plan for AWS Account access?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I was thinking what if my AWS Account gets deleted or is inaccessible one day? Has anyone implemented a solution for this? Can we backup from one AWS account and restore to another AWS account?

Currently am using Skeddly to backup my AWS instances, which is again stored in AWS itself.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things you can do, one is to make sure you have at least two administrator accounts, one that you use, and one that you store away in a safe place and only use for energencies.

The second is to setup a completely seperate AWS account as a 'backup', with its own set of credentials. You can grant cross-account access from your primary account, to your backup account but only allow the primary account to 'put' or backup objects to the backup account, so that even if your primary account is compromised, the attacker can't do harm to the second account from the primary account.

The actual process to backup your services on one account to another is going to vary depending on which services you are using, but the concept is the same - backup the data to s3 and then copy the data from s3 in your primary account to s3 in the backup account - and make sure the primary account only has enough access to the second account to 'put' things, not delete. Nobody in your company should have access to both of those sets of credentials (assuming your company is not tiny).

You don't want to be this company that was put out of business when there account was compromised:

[Hacker Puts Hosting Service Code Spaces Out of Business | Threatpost | The first stop for security news](https://threatpost.com/hacker-puts-hosting-service-code-spaces-out-of-business/106761/)

Also, this video, from AWS Reinvent 2015 (starting around 50 minutes in), listen to how AirBNB protects against these issues in just this way:

[AWS re:Invent 2015 | (DAT304) Amazon RDS for MySQL: Best Practices | youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHg8LD5KNC0)

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule for building in AWS should be that you automate everything.

Now, if you lose access to your account or it is compromised and everything is terminated then it's just a matter of running a simple process to bring back all your stateless components.

The big catch here is your stateful components such as your databases. For this I would recommend that you take regular backups of your databases and keep them somewhere off AWS (or somewhere that your account cannot delete at least such as in [Amazon Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/) with [Vault Lock](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/glacier-vault-lock/)).

For instance, you could have a scheduled job that takes a [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) of any MySQL databases you have and then SCPs them off AWS.

Now, if you lose your account then it's a simple matter of restoring the database backups to wherever you choose to rebuild (could be back in AWS under another account or even in the same account but just properly secured this time) and then running your automation process to rebuild all your other, stateless components.

Obviously there will be some loss of data as you can only go back to the last backup you have from your database.

Comment: Thanks.But I have 22 server + 3 RDS s in Singapore + N.California region.thoughts?

Comment: am looking for a complete backup plan for all my servers in AWS and not just recovering with DB. Imagine a tool which creates a replica of all servers in another AWS account.something similar to it.I was thinking to share backed up AMI's with another AWS account and create a copy if it there.(as a work around) thoughts?